# Android Tabactivity with ExpandableListActivity

Tags: android

I am beginner of Android.  I found the TabActivity with ExpandableListActivity example.
I have 3 tabs, Artics, Album, Songs.  In the Album, with AlbumActivity I would like
to list all albums.  I run the programme, when I click on Album it run into error to
force down.  Where I did wrong?

album_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_album"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AlbumActivity.java

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends ExpandableListActivity  {
...
...onCreate...
        setContentView(R.layout.album_list);
        registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

Comment: what is the exception in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Does your manifest list each of your activities (screen layout interfaces)? Simply not mentioning an activity will cause a crash.
Please provide a link or send me an archive of the example code you based your effort on, and a copy of your AndroidManifest.xml and your LOGCAT text copy.
In particular it is important to post the first EXCEPTIONs you find in LOGCAT when you run in in DEBUG instead of JAVA.
The AndroidManifest.xml needs an addition entry of the form:
    
        
for each activity class you may open with a create... in a file MyActivity.java in addition to the distinct  entry you have for the main activity that you launch first